# Assigning Cell Values to ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt while using Excel macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to use Excel macros to create a chart. I wanted to change its origin point from 0,0 to whatever point I desire.

For each graph it refers to a set of values in a range of cells that should be the origin. But when I run it I get a type mismatch error.

```
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisShow)
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Age Var").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 4
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 1.5
**ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = CDbl(Range("K2:M2").Value)**
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Age Var").Activate
```

Comment: take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 0):

**ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt** needs to get a value, you are setting it to a range of cells, that's why you are getting an error.

See code below, simplified and made it shorter:

```
' Assuming you meant "Age Var" as your chart's Name you want all your auto settings by VBA code
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Age Var").Activate
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisShow)
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 4
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 1.5

' modifed your Range to a Single Cell
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = CDbl(Range("K2").Value)
```